# Disable button base on condition using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

Currently I am trying to disable button based on the below condition with the current one partially working

The condition is a >= b should enable button

For example I have two dates actually based on the above condition the button should enable

12-Jun-2020 == 12-Jun-2020 button should enable
12-Jun-2020 >= 13-Jun-2020 button should enable

Here is my code

```
 buttondisable(){
   let condition = this.date1 <= this.date2;
   console.log(condition);
   return condition;
 }
```

Here is the my Html

```
<button color="primary" [disabled]="buttondisable()">Edit</button>
```

but the problem with the above ts code is if i select same date button is not enabling.

Comment: `a >= b` or `a <= b`?

Comment: What are types of date1 and date 2?

Comment: Is your condition ever true?

Comment: Can you do `console.log(this.date1, this.date2, condition)` when you are selecting the same date and tell us the log?